# HTML resize within php using width and height?

Tags: php, html, image, resize

I assumed this would work, but it turns out it's a no go.

```
"<img src="images/'.$id'.jpg" width="244" height="182"/>"
```

Does simple html work in this case or does it have to be php script?

Additional information : 
Initially I upload the image as a large image and I want to call it with the resize, but it is not giving me a resize.

```
$dynamicList .= '<div class="productHead"><a href="product.php?id='.$id.'">'.$product_name.'</a></div>
<div class="productPicture"><a href="product.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="inventory_images/'.$id'.jpg" width="244" height="182"/></a></div>
<div class="goToProduct"><a href="product.php?id='.$id.'">Check Out Product</a></div>';
```

Comment: It seems like it has to be a PHP script for this to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$element = '<img src="images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="244" height="182"/>';
```

would certainly work. in your original question, you had unescaped quotes. Its easier to use single quotes when echo-ing HTML since HTML uses double quotes. So you dont have to keep escaping them.

You can store HTML elements as strings in variables if you want to use them later in some place.

Comment: I think I'm understanding what you mean, but I realized this may be an incomplete question. I've failed to include that this is not an echo statement, but rather more similar to this.    

    $dynamicList .= <img src="inventory_images/'.$id'.jpg" width="244" height="182"/>;     

////which is within a while statement


Thanks so much for your quick reply!

Comment: Yes. you can store the HTML as a string in a php variable. Not a problem at all. I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish though

Comment: edit: added to original question.

Comment: you might want to add that as part of your question so people can give you a more complete answer :). and please format code correctly. its very difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out how to create code within comments. To see the output take a look at moniquetrinidadjewelry.com at the bottom left > under new arrivals.

Comment: When I look at the live version's HTML the width and height are not there in the img tag. When I add them (using chrome dev tools) the image is fine. So my guess is you are not pushing your local dev code to the server?

Comment: Hey Ahmed 
Thanks for sticking with me here.. I appreciate it.

That was my first thought and made sure this wasn't the issue. I also went behind the scenes to make sure the image resize code was in. When it didn't output I assumed it had to be done in a different way. That's where my first question arose from.

Comment: But it does not show up on the HTML page served by the server. I cant think of anything except that the code is not correctly pushed. You could try out adding something harmless like a `class="something"` to your tag and make sure that it is in the document being served (thus making sure the code is actually being correctly pushed?). I can't think of anything else. Its definitely not a PHP syntax error or something like that.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot Ahmed. I was editing the wrong file, but mistaken because of the new image being outputted. I saw change, but change unrelated. Sily mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad you got it working :)